# How to Verify Email Address for Forgot Password Feature in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, email

I have implemented the Forgot Password feature, which will send a reset link to the user email.  I also put some code to verify if it's a valid email address using a JavaScript library at the client side.

My question is how to check at the server side, so that when the email address is not in our database's users table, we will display a flash error message; If it is in our users table, we will send out the password reset link.

I'm using `Devise` for user management.

Comment: Forgot password functionality is already built in to devise

Comment: Have you had any luck with this so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precise functionality you've depicted ships with Devise. To enable it, you'll need to declare your Devise model as being `:recoverable`:

```
# app/models/user.rb (assuming that User is a Devise model)
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :recoverable
```

Then, you can access the password recovery form by visiting `http://yourdomain/users/password/new`. Presuming you haven't overridden/subclassed `Devise::PasswordsController`, you'll be granted all the functionality you need directly out-of-the-box.

Comment: Later, I discussed with my co-workers, and it's by design that we don't want to verify the email address when the user tries to reset the password, because it could be a security issue to let the user know if an email address is in our database or not.